# How to run Windows graphic application via ssh?

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh

When connecting to `Windows` via `ssh`, the used `shell` is the `PowerShell`.

So I tried these two commands using the `PowerShell` directly in `Windows`, not via `ssh`, and this happened:
`start calc` **->** The calculator **process is started** and the calculator **GUI is opened**
`start cmd` **->** The command prompt **process is started** and the command prompt **GUI is opened**

Then I tried the same accessing `Windows` via `ssh`, and this happened:
`start calc` **->** The calculator **process is started** and the calculator **GUI is opened**
`start cmd` **->** The command prompt **process is started** and the command prompt **GUI is NOT opened**

So the only difference is in the opening of the command prompt `GUI`.

What are the differences between the two processes, in this case the calculator and the command prompt, but in general between this two types of `GUI` management?
Is there a way (such as a parameter) to force the `GUI` to open?